# Terminal autocomplete doesn't work properly

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-minimal, auto-completion

If I start typing a command like `apt-g` after hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>, the shell completes the command to `apt-get`, but for the second part of the command like `install`, if I enter some characters like `insta`, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>, doesn't complete it to `install`.

Another example: after I enter `sudo` hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't complete anything. for example: `sudo apt-ge` [<kbd>tab</kbd>] and nothing.

I installed Ubuntu using mini iso (40MB network installer), so maybe there is a config that I missed!

I've added this code to my `.bashrc` but still it does not works:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I have also checked the permission of `.bashrc` and it's `-rw-r--r--`.

I also source the `.bashrc` after changes using `source .bashrc` to apply the changes to the new environment but still no effects.

I use `xfce4-terminal` so I thought it might be the terminal and not the bash.

But editing:

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

And changing:

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"/>
```

to:

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="empty"/>
```

Doesn't makes any difference too.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`bash-completion` is a set of bash scripts which enables customized completion for specific commands.

This is not just for files and directories, but also e.g. for the commands. So you type partial of commands and by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> we get a auto completion of commands.

#### Installation

**Step 1:** Install bash-completion

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

And some times it works if we re-installed it by the follwing command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion
```

**Step 2:** Enable bash-completion in your `.bashrc` file

Open your `gedit ~/.bashrc` and if these content doesn't exist there, add them at the end of it and save it.

```bsh
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

**Important:** After changing the file you need to source your  `~/.bashrc` with `source ~/.bashrc` or reopen your Terminal. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I would like to confirm that adding the above block of code to the ~/.bashrc file did work for me. Just one comment; you don't really need to log out and log in again to make it work (you may not want to terminate what you work in), you could just run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I had to reopen the Terminal in order for it to work!

Comment: Completion suddenly stopped working for me, the above steps do not fix the issue. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the issue? On ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Step 2 does it for me. Or get the template from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

Comment: not works with su hyphen (at least for Arch linux) (for example su - username)

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo not sure what issue you are facing you may look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219342/72456 it helps, else open your own question for the problem you have.

Comment: for me, only chmod can't autocomplete, any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure which part did it, since I tried all three, but this worked. I had the issue that bash only autocompleted the second parameter, not the first, e.g. `cd install/<TAB>` would not show the folders inside install, but `time cd install/<TAB>` would work.

Comment: What eventually solved this issue for me was changing the user's shell, via this answer https://serverfault.com/a/99791/185200

Answer (score 36):

If your case is terminal tab not working under Xfce, the solution is as follows:

1. Open *Application Menu* > *Settings* > *Window Manager*.
2. Click on '*Keyboard*' tab.
3. Clear the '*Switch window for same application*' setting.

[image: Window Manager screenshot how to clear switch window for same application]

I've found the solution [here](https://www.starnet.com/xwin32kb/tab-key-not-working-when-using-xfce-desktop/).

Comment: Tried accepted awnser, but everything was already in place. This was indeed the solution for me.

Comment: Still the solution I needed as of May 2018.

Comment: Needed this once I connected through xrdp

Answer (score 14):

You may also be in a shell that doesn't support auto complete (ex: Bourne Shell | SH). If you want BASH auto complete you need to switch shells, say to BASH (Bourne Again SHell) instead with the command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Source: [Ubuntu Wiki - Changing Shells](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells)

Comment: Alternatively just hit `bash` and it works

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to execute a script `./myScript.sh`, and typing `./my[tab]` would not auto-complete.

I had to add execute permissions to the file and auto-completion worked.