# Bash auto completion

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I want completion like in emacs that if there is only a sole completion to the command you are typing, than you don't need to type it all.

For example:

```
package ins
```

is enough instead of typing the whole:

```
package install
```

Is there a package or script that does that?

I am looking for a solution that doesn't require hitting the tab key but rather hitting the enter straight away and having a script do the auto completion before running the command.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` does that by default if the `bash-completion` package is installed, just type e.g.

```
> apt i
```

press <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> and you'll get

```
> apt install
```

If there are multiple matches, pressing <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> another time will display a list of them., e.g.

```
> ap
```

<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>

*nothing happens*

<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd>

```
aplay                         apport-bug                    apt                           aptdcon                       aptitude-curses
aplaymidi                     apport-cli                    apt-add-repository            apt-extracttemplates          aptitude-run-state-bundle
apm_available                 apport-collect                apt-cache                     apt-ftparchive                apt-key
apparmor_parser               apport-unpack                 apt-cdrom                     apt-get                       apt-mark
apparmor_status               appres                        apt-config                    aptitude                      apt-sortpkgs
applygnupgdefaults            apropos                       aptd                          aptitude-create-state-bundle
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast response, I am aware of this but am looking for auto completion without the need of pressing the tab key.

Comment: @EdenK You're welcome! Did I understand your question correctly, does this solve your problem? If not please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956916/edit) your question and add details about what you want.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in which I for instance can type "package ins" and hit enter rather than hitting the tab key.
I know it only takes a second to hit the tab key but I am curious if such solution exists.

Comment: @EdenK Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956916/edit) your question and add this information there!

Comment: @Edenk you could use `fish shell`

Comment: Same comment for your answer "OP wants `RETURN` to complete **and** execute the command in one step" not with `TAB` :D

Comment: @αғsнιη In my defense, I wrote this when OP had not yet made that clear. ;D However, other people finding this question will probably want that, so I'll leave it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `fish shell` would be in order here. To install:

1. Download from [here](https://fishshell.com/)
2. Then use this [tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html) to assist you learning.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly `fish` behaves when it comes to autocompletion?

Comment: Have you used it before?

Comment: See this: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#autosuggestions

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `bash-completion`.
If already installed, you need to source it:

```
source /etc/bash_completion
```

You can add it in your .bashrc file.
You can add custom completions in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is you want **Bash Completion**, please refer to the post [Terminal autocomplete doesn't work properly](https://askubuntu.com/q/545540/283843), else if you need <kbd>Enter</kbd> become as like <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> and also execute that command immediately, then you need to add the command below in your `~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc` it.

```
bind 'RET:"\C-i\C-j"'
```

The `RET` is shortened for `RETURN`; You could use `"\C-M"` instead as well which is stands for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.