# Tab auto-completion doesn't work for argument for a non root user on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: command-line, 18.04, shortcut-keys, auto-completion

For an ordinary user on Ubuntu 18.04.1 the tab key doesn't work for a command argument.

For example, entering `systemctl sta` and pressing the tab doesn't produce a match for "start status".

It works for the root user.  The example below is for the root user:

systemctl sta<press tab key>
    start   status

The above functions as expected.
 
However, it doesn't work for a non-root user.
systemctl sta<press tab key>
did not match any argument.

It happened after updating from 16.04 to 18.04.1.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/545540/terminal-autocomplete-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: Above link solved the problem