# Tab auto-completetion not working when executing python scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

Tab auto-completion/double pressing tab does not show files or autocomplete file, only showing folders while executing python scripts with argparse arguments.

Expected behaviour:

```
python ~/scripts/script.py -arg `~/folder/folder_with_files_and_more_folders/`
```

"tab tab"

```
list of files and folders/autocompletes if I give enough of the file name
```

What is happening:

```
python ~/scripts/script.py -arg `~/folder/folder_with_files_and_more_folders/`
```

"tab tab"

```
list of folders
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal autocomplete doesn't work properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545540/terminal-autocomplete-doesnt-work-properly)