# Terminal autocomplete doesn't work after some updates

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I have been using Ubuntu for quite some time now. At first everything worked good. After some update that was released lately (probably less than 2 months), terminal does not autocomplete commands any more.

When I try to type something and try to autocomplete it with tab... it just does nothing.

I tried to look at some solutions on this site including this

[Terminal autocomplete doesn't work properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545540/terminal-autocomplete-doesnt-work-properly)

But that did not work. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, both 20.04.2.0 and 21.04, but the problem persists.

Before when I used the autocomplete function by pressing the tab key, I could hear a beep from the PC, but I do not hear the beep anymore.

Any help please??

Comment: You may try to overwrite your bash configuration files with the default ones: `cp /etc/skel/.* ~`. Exit and restart terminal to see changes. The package `bash-completion` should be installed by default.

Comment: Hi @vanadium

Can you please write the full command how can it be done?
I get the following result when i try to execute the command above 

 cp /etc/skel/.* ~
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/etc/skel/.'

Comment: Don't worry, that is because of the `.*`. That also selects `.`, the current directory, besides the hidden files you want to copy, hence the warning. The files are copied, though. If that does not help, perhaps temporarily create a new account to see if the issue persists there. If no, then it is confirmed that this is a problem with your current user configuration.

Comment: Sorry none of the above solutions worked... 

Any other suggestion?

Comment: So it does not work on another, new account, and even not after reinstalling???

Comment: Yes that is right. It does not work neither with new account, nor with new installation.